# The Mix manifest does not exist

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, vuex, laravel-mix

i'm created simple laravel project with this [Laravel-Vue SPA starter project template](https://github.com/cretueusebiu/laravel-vue-spa) and im uploaded this project to ubuntu server. all settings corect but i run this project returns this error "The Mix manifest does not exist. (View: /var/www/html/project/resources/views/index.blade.php)".

please anyone help me. i'm new in laravel.

Comment: I think you need to run console command `npm run dev` or if you dont have node_module files run `npm install` then `npm run dev`

Comment: already install npm install and composer install

Answer (score 5):

I think it's because you separated your laravel files from public folder.

and `public_path()` returns wrong path.

for being sure try `dd(public_path())`.

If that was wrong, you have to correct paths in your index.php file and add this code:

```
$app->bind('path.public', function() {
return __DIR__;
});
```

I had the same issue and found that the problem is this.

Maybe it's late to answer this question but it may help others.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same error. This resolved it for me. `npm run production`

I tried `npm run dev` but it never created the `manifest.js`.

Comment: Thanks. Worked for me and should be the selected answer.

Answer (score 2):

if you dont have `node_modules` folder, run `npm install` and then run `npm run dev`.

`mix()` helper function by default looks for the manifest json file in directory `/public/manifest-json.js`. check this file to exist.

Comment: For me manifest-json.js doesn't exist in my working version. There's a mix-manifest.json in the public folder and a manifest.js in the public/js folder but copying those to my broken environment doesn't fix anything.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it will be useful for someone, when I try to visit this URL `example.com/nova/login` I find this error 
`The Mix manifest does not exist.
 (View: example/nova/resources/views/auth/layout.blade.php)`

In my case executing next command was wrong:

`npm run production`

`npm run dev`

`php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Laravel\Horizon\HorizonServiceProvider"`

etc.

I just forgot to install Nova library after I has recovered project, `php artisan nova:install`

Answer (score 1):

Simply change the `mix(css/app.css)` to `{!! asset('css/app') !!}`

Answer (score 0):

You should create a symlink of storage/app/public

```
php artisan storage:link
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok so most here are giving solutions but they don't explain it, basically best practice if you are using a shared hosting for Laravel you put the project folder outside public_html then contents inside public you put them in public_html.

So what you need to do is don't delete the public folder in your project root and only put the
`mix-manifest.json`
file in the public folder that is in the root of your project, that will solve this issue

Answer (score 0):

In App\Providers\AppServiceProvider.php:

```
public function register()
{
    /**
     * Set the public path.
     */
    $this->app->bind('path.public', function() {
         return 'public path';
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Are you sure, "h151778" is a folder on the thread owners server?

Comment: No I made a mistake, it was only a sample which was mine

Answer (score 0):

Run following commands in terminal.

```
npm install laravel-mix@latest

npm run dev
```