# Laravel 5.7 : The Mix manifest does not exist error

Tags: laravel-5, npm, npm-install, laravel-mix

I am a newbie to Laravel 5.7 and getting an error as follows:

> The Mix manifest does not exist. (View:
> /var/www/html/laravel/resources/views/frontend/layouts/app.blade.php)
> (View:
> /var/www/html/laravel/resources/views/frontend/layouts/app.blade.php)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you run `npm run dev` or `yarn dev`? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48973311/the-mix-manifest-does-not-exist

Comment: Did you get solution for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try to run:

```
npm install
```

and then

`npm run dev` or `npm run watch`

Answer (score 0):

first install npm dependency if not install

```
npm install
```

then run production command

```
npm run production
```

Answer (score 0):

The Mix Manifest does not exist php.#46 laravel 8.  (resources\views\layouts\guest.blade.php)

let we see few lines to fix this error:
1.first install latest version ***npm*.**
2.install latest version **node(minimumV12.4)**.
3.install the MIX using these commands
**npm init -y** then
**npm install laravel-mix --save-dev**.
4.After that just compile the css and js files using this command
**npx mix**
now we will get a message **webpack compiled successfully**
then we can run the artisan using **php artisan serve**.I hope to help this anyone